# Can I wrap a List object without copying?

Tags: java, list, extends

I have a `List<List<Object>>`, but I don't want to always write that out wherever I use it, which also increases readability. So I wanted to wrap it in an object called `ValueSheet`. 
 This is what I've done, but it creates massive overhead, because it creates a copy of the List, which is not necessary:

```
public class ValueSheet extends ArrayList<List<Object>> {

    public ValueSheet(List<List<Object>> values) {
        super(values);
    }

}
```

would it be possible to do that without overhead while preserving the fact that this Object is a `List<List<Object>>`? This means that I am NOT looking for this:

```
public class ValueSheet {

    List<List<Object>> values;

    public ValueSheet(List<List<Object>> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

}
```

PS: NO, I can not instantiate a `ValueSheet` directly, because the `List<List<Object>>` is provided from external sources.

Comment: Haven't tested this, but shouldn't it be possible to use the first class you already made by replacing all instances of `new List<List<Object>>()` with `new ValueSheet()`? You talk about copying as though you plan to first create the `List` object, and then use `new ValueSheet(existingList)`, but you shouldn't need to do it that way.

Comment: A <List<List<Object>> contains a set of Lists which contains a set of Objects, right.  If you don't put anything into it,won't have anything in it.   If you have an object that knows how to fetch the objects from some external List<List<Object>> then it is not, itself a <List<List<Object>> now is it?   A quick answer to your question would be "no, you can't do that."  A longer answer would be to give you a technique that solves the real problem you are trying to address.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You can combine the two solutions by using the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Guava makes this easy with its [`ForwardingList`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html). Though in my opinion you're taking a hacky approach to the problem. If your model is indeed `List<List<Object>>` you shouldn't be disguising it as another type. And if it can be viewed as a custom type, the second approach (that you've rejected) is more correct.

Comment: Why are you *inheriting* from `ArrayList`? Does your `ValueSheet` qualify to **be an**   `ArrayList`?

Comment: I inherited from Arraylist just for demonstration. The `List<List<Object>>` is given to me from external source.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is not really designed for extension.
Its parent class, `AbstractList` is designed for extension,
and it may be suitable for your purpose. Here's a minimal example:

```
public class ValueSheet extends AbstractList<List<Object>> {

  private final List<List<Object>> values;

  ValueSheet(List<List<Object>> values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

  @Override
  public List<Object> get(int index) {
    return values.get(index);
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return values.size();
  }
}
```

Note that calling methods that modify the list will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.
If you need any of those methods,
you will need to override and implement them yourself.
(It could be as simple as delegating to the underlying list.)

Comment: This can result in sub-optimal performance for many (most?) methods with custom implementations in `ArrayList`.

Comment: @shmosel can you please give an example?

Comment: @shmosel the performance depends on the implementation of `values`. If `values` is an instance of `ArrayList`, the performance will be the same as an `ArrayList`

Comment: @rollback Any method that's inherited from `AbstractList` and overridden in `ArrayList` is overridden for some benefit in performance or functionality. For example, `remove()` won't work at all in this example.

Comment: @shmosel I think you don't get my point. All methods in `ValueSheet` simply call the same method on `values`. That means, the performance depends on the List implementation of `values`. That may be an `LinkedList`, `ArrayList` or any other implementation of `List`.

Comment: @rollback I see now. The original version of this answer didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to create your `ValueSheet` with a copy constructor in the first place?
Try refactoring your code to work directly with `ValueSheet`, and simply never instantiate a `List<List<Object>>`.